# file manager is not clearing from older app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I have an app in my code that loads a file into a Bluetooth device, but it seems like if I change that file for the new version of the app it doesn't update it if I just reinstall it. I have to actually delete the app and install it again. Anyone know why? Is there some cache storing?

```
   NSString *fileInDocuments = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"samplefile_pack.bin"];
   NSLog(@"File: %@", fileInDocuments);
   if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileInDocuments ] == NO) {
   NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"samplefile_pack" ofType:@"bin"];
  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:fileInDocuments error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming v1 of your app has the same code as the v2 of your app posted in your question. Assuming this is true, the behavior you see makes perfect sense.

A user runs v1 of your app. The file isn't in the Documents folder so it gets copied from the app bundle. Now, every time they run your app, the file exists and that copy in Documents is used.

Now the user updates to v2 of your app. The same check is made. The file already exists in Documents so nothing is copied.

Since your question implies that you want an updated copy of this file installed the 1st time v2 of the app is run, you need to detect whether the user currently has the file from v1 or v2 in the Documents folder.

There are a few ways to solve this. One option is to rename the file to something like `samplefile_pack2.bin`. Then your check can be for the new file name. You can also check for the old one and delete it if it makes sense.

Comment: I do change the file to pack2, but still it gets the first one. So I wouldn't need to check if the old one gets deleted or not

Comment: What do you mean it still gets the first one?

Comment: Yes which is very weird

Comment: What's weird? I asked you a question since I didnt understand your comment.

Comment: @user3281743 are you saying that file still show structure of v1 and not showing changes you have made in the v2 ?

Comment: Yes even if I put pack2 it still gets pack1 when it's not even in the app anymore.
@Pyro yes

Comment: You probably need to do a clean build otherwise your app will contain both files in the app bundle.